# Why laravel migrate:fresh takes a long time for 422 tables?

Tags: php, laravel, migrate

I have a Laravel project and I'm using this command to migrate a database every time I want to create a new project

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

It was working fine, but after 3 years of working on it I've reached 422 tables and now when I want to migrate it takes almost 5 to 10 minutes at least to complete a migrate job.

I can wait without problems in `localhost`, but my biggest problem is when I use the [`LaravelInstaller`](https://github.com/rashidlaasri/LaravelInstaller) library to add an installer feature to the project.

It takes a long time and eventually it returns the next error

> internal server error 500

So in order to make this installation work with such long durations, I have to change `Max time limit` in `php.ini` to solve this issue.

Is there any way to speed up the migration?

Thanks

Comment: _422 table_ Please tell me this is not real.

Comment: i don't understand, your problem on migration is, taking long time for that 422 tables on old project, or it happen when you try to use with `Installer`?

Comment: I would suggest creating a clean dump of the database and handing that over instead of trying to migrate from fresh

Comment: And, why you have `422` table, after all a fresh laravel migration shouldn't be a problem when there's no data...

Comment: sir yes 422 table its erp system with 32 Modules and many many table

Comment: For more info try to set laravel debug to true, to get more info, then add it to your question.

Comment: its not problem with laravel to set debut true or false its becuase there is many tables its tack long time im asking is there anyway to increse the speed of migration ?

Comment: @softya It's better to reconsider your DB design. I would say this is more critical than this timeout issue you are facing which is unlikely to have any scope of optimization since there will be roundtrips between application server and database server when you go live.

Comment: @softya you said, you have `internal server error 500`. base on that, I've said set it true, to find out what is happening during installation process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer to speed-up issue, not `internal server error 500`, because there's not any details related to issue that causing that error.

I'm assuming you're using `Laravel 8` at least, and base on that you can try `Schema Dump`, which It's added to creates a dump of the current schema.

Here's the command :

```
php artisan schema:dump

# Below command is taken from below link, in case of more help, don't hesitate 
# to read the docs
# Dump the current database schema and prune all existing migrations...
php artisan schema:dump --prune
```

You have this issue simply because you've a huge list of migration files that were created, and in this case, in general, doing a migration:fresh should not take so much time, even for `422` table, but you have this issues, because of repeating this process and make list bigger in years.

Here's the link to [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#squashing-migrations)